# How to add .php extension for particular file?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

In my wordpress website i used a **htaccess code to remove php extension**. Then I again **used a code to add php extension**.

After that **all files are accessible but when I click on plugins and contactform7 from my dashboard it opens https://ecxsolution.roundabouttech.com/wp-admin/plugins without extension and string after it and shows file not found.**

I am not able to see all my forms even. Can somebody tell me how should I *change .htaccess file to add extension for this particular file*?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: There's nothing in these rules to add or remove file extensions. Maybe there are other rules?

Comment: but previously i removed the php extension